# Need solution to freezing column in GridView that works in IE8+

Tags: gridview

I've been searching for too long now to find a solution to column freezing in a GridView. I've found many answers, but virtually all of them require CSS expressions, which were eliminated in IE8. Is there a solution to this problem?

So, just for clarity, I have an existing grid that I'm tasked with adding this new feature. I need to be able  to dynamically freeze the first few columns (like in Excel). Obviously, the column headers will need to be frozen simultaneously. It doesn't have to be supported on anything but IE8+.

In the older DataGridView, there was a column property that allowed you to do this very thing:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["AddToCartButton"].Frozen = true;
```

Unfortunately, that appears to have been removed from GridView. To be fair, I found that on the tubes, but I've never actually used it, so no clue if it works or how.

Is there an alternative method for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Each `DataGridViewColumn`, `DataGridViewRow`, and `DataGridViewCell` has a `ReadOnly` attribute that you can set to `true`. A good practice is to also set the column's (or row's or cell's) `InheritedStyle.BackColor` to `System.Drawing.Color.LightGray`

Answer (score 0):

i wrote jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, it can be apply to GridView. see the image:
[image]

looking more on website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Supported Browsers

- Internet Explorer 7, 8 (IE 9 Compatibility)
- Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112)
- Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Preview
- Google Chrome(23.0.1271.64 m)
- Mozilla Firefox (16.0.2)
- Apple Safari (5.1.7)